# Excluding rows that have the same significance but different values

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data:

```
Time                    ID              Context                     Value
----------------------- --------------- ----------                  -----
2021-02-03 10:07:32.777 359586015047527 TwigStatus                  4
2021-02-03 10:07:32.777 359586015047527 SafeProtectDeviceConnected  False
2021-02-03 10:07:32.580 359586015047527 ConnectionLost              True
```

All rows have the same semantics. I need a query to exclude them all because of the second row (Context = `SafeProtectDeviceConnected`)

So with the dataset above, the result set would be:

```
Time                    ID              Context                     Value
----------------------- --------------- ----------                  -----
```

if the dataset is:

```
Time                    ID              Context                     Value
----------------------- --------------- ----------                  -----
2021-02-03 10:07:32.777 359586015047527 TwigStatus                  4
2021-02-03 10:07:32.580 359586015047527 ConnectionLost              True
```

I'd like to have only one row, whatever the row.

And finally if the dataset is:

```
Time                    ID              Context                     Value
----------------------- --------------- ----------                  -----
2021-02-03 10:07:32.580 359586015047527 ConnectionLost              True
```

I'd like this one row to be returned.

I've tried to add new columns to my dataset within my SELECT statement :

```sql
row_number() over (partition by ID order by Time desc) AS row_num
```

and:

```sql
CASE WHEN Context = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' THEN 1 WHEN Context = 'TwigStatus' THEN 2 WHEN Context = 'ConnectionLost' THEN 3 END AS row_num2
```

But I can't wrap my head over a filtering clause to get the desired result.

---

**EDIT**: The business logic is this:

- A device is telling a server that it is being stopped (TwigStatus/SafeProtectDeviceConnected)
- A device is also sending a ping to the server to tell it is still online.

  - If the device has not sent a ping for predefined timeout, the server considers that the server has lost connection (ConnectionLost)

This is the best case scenario.

Because everything could go wrong and to maintain compatibility with existing applications and tooling, We could have three, two or one record in the database to tell that the device is offline.

Comment: Quote blocks are for quotes, not code. Put code in Code Fences, please.

Comment: I don't follow, what do you mean with "All rows have the same semantics"?

Comment: Sorry, they have the same significance from a business point of view.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT can you explain the business logic? If we don't know what logic you are trying to implement its going to be hard to help.

Comment: What do you mean by `semantics` or `significance` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted ?

use `NOT EXISTS()` to obtain `ID` that does not contain `SafeProtectDeviceConnected`. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to obtain just one row per ID

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, rn = row_number() over (partition by T.ID order by T.Time)
    FROM   yourtable T
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS
    (
          SELECT *
          FROM   yourtable X
          WHERE  X.ID = T.ID
          AND    X.Context = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected'
    )    
) D
WHERE D.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without a self-join, using `COUNT() OVER`. This may be more or less performant than the other answer, you  need to test.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by T.ID order by T.Time),
        c = count(case when X.Context = 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected' then 1 end) over (partition by T.ID)
    FROM   yourtable T
) D
WHERE D.rn = 1 AND c = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply Copy and paste it. you got your answer simply!

```
CREATE TABLE #data (Time_data  NVARCHAR(MAX), ID BIGINT, Context NVARCHAR(100), Value nvarchar(20))
GO

INSERT INTO #data VALUES
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.777', 359586015047527, 'TwigStatus', '4'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.777', 359586015047527, 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected',  'False'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.580', 359586015047527, 'ConnectionLost',  'True'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.580', 359586015047529, 'ConnectionLost',  'True'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.580', 359586015047529, 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected',  '4'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.580', 3595860150475230, 'TwigStatus',  '4'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.580', 3595860150475230, 'ConnectionLost',  '4'),
('2021-02-03 10:07:32.580', 3595860150475230, 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected',  '4')

select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by Time_data desc) AS seq 
INTO #finaldata
FROM #data
where Context <> 'SafeProtectDeviceConnected'

select *from #finaldata where seq=1

----------
```

Comment: Learn how to use derived tables, see the other answers